# Parse html WITHOUT nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, parsing

I'm working on a coding challenge for a company where they've asked me to setup an api for parsing out certain content from a HTML document (h1, h2, h3 tags and links). However when I asked about using outside libraries, specifically Nokogiri, the person I was speaking to said not to use it if possible (not sure if they're a dev or not).

Is there any good way to do this? The only way I can think of is with lots of `split`'s since everything I've read says using regex's here is not the right way to go. Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Why* did they ask you not to use Nokogiri, because they want to see how you solve the problem otherwise?

Comment: I don't recommend that as there are many complexities e.g when you have nested divs.

Comment: @Brennan I guess so, but since I'm inclined to think the person I'm emailing with isn't a dev I don't think they know how much more difficult that makes this task.

Comment: Them asking you to not use a library for this is definitely kind of ridiculous, IMO. It's reinventing the wheel a bit too much

Comment: Yeah I've already started to do it with Nokogiri since I really don't think I can complete the challenge without it, I just wanted to see if anyone knew of any other ways to do it that I might not be thinking of